# Unexpected value read from socket fd

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, file-descriptor

Implementing a TCP server/client chat, I wanted to validate that the username of a new client  doesn't exist already.
The server's code part is:

```
do
{
    err=0;
    if(write(socketFd[(int)idx], nickMsg, strlen(nickMsg))<0)
        perror("write");
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    read(socketFd[(int)idx], buff, sizeof(buff));
    for(i=0; i<supportedUsrsNum; i++)
    {
        if(*names[i]!=0)
        {
            if(strncmp(buff, names[i], strlen(buff))==0)
            {
                err=-1;
                write(socketFd[(int)idx], usrExstMsg, strlen(usrExstMsg));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!err)
        break;
}
while(err==-1);
```

and the client writes:

```
do
{
    gets(sendBuff);
    write(sockFd, &sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff));
    sleep(1);
}while(1);
```

When the second client tries an existing name, the server detects it and goes for a second iteration, in which its read() gets an ASCII value of 3, though no further input occurred on the client side. What am I missing and how do I get to re-read a new value from the client?

Comment: Don't use `gets()`; use `fgets()`.  You can't prevent buffer overflows with `gets()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler looks like mighty `gets()` caused the trouble along with my wrong length writing. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. My `gets()` comment is a knee-jerk reaction to seeing the function used. There are lots of error checks missing, including (crucially), checking the return value from `read()`. Your client-side `write()` should be sending `strlen(sendBuff)` rather than `sizeof(sendBuff)` bytes, possibly with a `+1` to send a terminal null too. If you don't send the null over the wire, the reading code won't receive it, and the received string may not be null-terminated (unless you make sure it is). Colin D Bennett has written up these issues in the accepted answer, so all's well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the `read()` is not actually reading ASCII 3 but readings zero bytes. Perhaps an error condition occurred. Always check the return value of the call to `read()` since

1. It may return with a failure condition, or
2. It may read fewer than the requested number of bytes.

ALSO:
The client is sending the ENTIRE 'sendBuff' with this line:

```
write(sockFd, &sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff));
```

where you probably want to only send the string itself (with some terminating character like '\0' or '\n').  Using `sizeof(sendBuff)` will send the actual text entered at `gets()`, the '\0' terminator, and then any random bytes that already existed in `sendBuff` before the call to `gets()`.

Change that line to something like

```
write(sockFd, &sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff) + 1);
```

to write the text and the '\0' only, and not any extra garbage after it.

ALSO, don't use `gets()`. IT IS EVIL. (Thanks Jonathan Leffler for the reminder on this.)

Comment: I changed to `fgets` with your `strlen(sendBuff)+1`. works like a charm. Thanks!!